# AngularJS - testing when using module approuch

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-filter

I have a problem with my test set-up. It does work when everything in a single file, it does not when code is spread across multiple files.

When the code is spread as per below, I get an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: twoPlusTwoFilterProvider <- twoPlusTwoFilter`

```
// js/index.js
angular.module('app', []);

// js/twoPlusTwoFilter.js
angular.module('app').filter('hex', function hex(){
    return function(input){
        return input+input; 
    }
});

// here is my test
describe('check sanity', function() {

    beforeEach( module('app') );

    it('should return 4', inject( function(hexFilter) {
        expect( hexFilter(2) ).toEqual(4);
    }));

});
```

Just FYI I am including angular-mocks in the karma conf. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading all of the files in karma.conf.js?

Comment: WHat is `twoPlusTwoFilter`?

Comment: @marneborn - yes, all libs, sources & tests..

Comment: Name of your filter is `hex` but you cannot inject it directly you need to inject filterprovider

Comment: @PSL  - `filterprovider` ? please tell us more ;)

Comment: @PSL  - `twoPlusTwoFilter` - please ingore, it's copy-paste-driven-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try inject [filterprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider) and get `hex` filter.

```
var $filter;

beforeEach(function () {
   module('app');
});

beforeEach( inject(function (_$filter_) { //<-- Get the filter provider
   $filter = _$filter_;
}));

it('should return 4', function () {
   expect( $filter('hex')(2) ).toEqual(4); //Not get your `hex` filter and run it
});
```

Or inject it with filter prefix.

```
beforeEach( inject(function (_hexFilter_) {
   $filter = _hexFilter_;
}));
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yhupvW?p=preview)**

> Filters are just functions which transform input to an output. However filters need to be Dependency Injected. To achieve this a filter definition consists of a factory function which is annotated with dependencies and is responsible for creating a filter function.

Comment: Is my inline `inject(function(filterNameHere){}) ` not good enough??

Comment: All works, thanks! Please tell us more about filterProvider & inject

Comment: @Iladarsda I have provided official documentation link along with an excerpt in the answer...

Comment: Does it work the same for providers/services (no http calls withing them)?